# Sitecore not resolving rich text editor URLS in page renders

Tags: url, hyperlink, sitecore, pipeline, rte

We're having issues inserting links into rich text in Sitecore 6.1.0. When a link to a sitecore item is inserted, it is outputted as:

`http://domain/~/link.aspx?_id=8A035DC067A64E2CBBE2662F6DB53BC5&_z=z`

Rather than the actual resolved url:

`http://domain/path/to/page.aspx`

[This article](http://www.experimentsincode.com/blog/post/sitecore-6-cache-clearing-and-links) confirms that this should be resolved in the render pipeline:

> in Sitecore 6 it inserts a specially
>   formatted link that contains the Guid
>   of the item you want to link to, then
>   when the item is rendered the special
>   link is replaced with the actual link
>   to the item

The pipeline has the method `ShortenLinks` added in web.config

```xml
<convertToRuntimeHtml>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.PrepareHtml, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.ShortenLinks, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.SetImageSizes, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.ConvertWebControls, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.FixBullets, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.ConvertToRuntimeHtml.FinalizeHtml, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
</convertToRuntimeHtml>
```

So I really can't see why links are still rendering in ID format rather than as full SEO-tastic urls. Anyone got any clues?

Thanks, Adam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be the default behaviour if you are using sc:fld to render field values. This is legacy behaviour left from Sitecore 5 which did not replace the guids in item links.

If you want to use Sitecore 6's new functionality, you must use sc:field instead

Comment: To expand on this answer a bit, the <renderField /> pipeline is where links are "expanded" from the ID format mentioned into a full URL. The sc:field extension method invokes the renderField pipeline if you use XSL. If you're using code-behind to render links, you can use the FieldRenderer class. You can also use the FieldRenderer control in your layouts/sublayouts (or any other control derived from the FieldRenderer control).

This document gives you a little background on the FieldRenderer control:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Presentation%20Component%20Reference.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are dealing with a large amount of code changes to implement FieldRenderer, might be worth to consider using Sitecore.Links.LinkManager.ExpandDynamicLinks(string text, UrlOptions options). It parses links and references to media items that Rich Text field might contain.

Comment: Using your suggested functionality still works great if you are working with a code-generation architecture, where you rely on the raw field value and want the links replaced.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into something similar.. My client was using a sitecore placeholder , that also doesn't render the links properly. As stated by the answers I ended using a field render:

```xml
<sc:FieldRenderer runat="server" ID="frBody" FieldName="Body"/>
```