# Sitecore links inserted in Rich Text editor are not resolved to user friendly URLs

Tags: url, hyperlink, sitecore, rich-text-editor

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229943/sitecore-not-resolving-rich-text-editor-urls-in-page-renders) but I'm not sure how to actually apply the answers.

I have a basic template that just has one Rich Text field called Body. The layout looks like this:

```
<div style="min-height: 38px">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litBodyContent"/>
</div>
```

I place it on the page with the Page Editor and enter some text into it. When I insert a link, it inserts it using the item ID rather than resolving it to a user friendly path:

```
<a href="~/link.aspx?_id=D9D103AD60DA4B318521801ADA863222&amp;_z=z">Go to another page</a>
```

when it should look like

```
<a href="/blog/2016/february/erica-test-entry">Go to another page</a>
```

What do I need to do to make the Rich Text editor resolve user friendly URLs?

Edit: Here's the codebehind for the Body Text

```
public override void Initialize()
{
    litBodyContent.Text = Html.Editable(GlassItem, item => item.Body);
}
```

Edit 2: This is one component that uses the Rich Text field, but I really need a universal fix so that any component that uses the Rich Text field will render links correctly. I don't want to have to manually fix every place that has a Rich Text field.

Comment: Are they only "not friendly" when you check them in RTE or are they also "not friendly" when you see published page? Those "not friendly" links are called `Dynamic Links` in Sitecore and they should be decoded into user friendly links while generating a page.

Comment: No, they display the item IDs still when I view the published page

Comment: How is the RT field rendered on the page?

Comment: It's a field in a component that is dropped on the page

Comment: I added some extra information including the code for the layout, which is just an asp:Literal inside a div

Comment: Use Sitecore `FieldRenderer` or `sc:Text` instead of `Literal`

Comment: Is the Body property decorated with a SitecoreField attribute and is it marked as SitecoreFieldType.RichText? Html.Editable should cover that.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the attribute in the model.

If you have **SitecoreFieldSettings.RichTextRaw** attribute, it will **NOT** pass through render pipeline and returns the RAW HTML. Instead if you use **Default** (**SitecoreFieldSettings.Default**), rich text content will go through render pipeline and url will be in friendly format.

http://docs.glass.lu/html/d44739b2-5f0e-d862-f62c-86c50f0b262f.htm

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43261752/3016347

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplica‌​te-answer-to-several-questions)